# how auto restart app when update finished?

Tags: android

After google I decide to do like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Because the device is rooted, so use below codes to update:

```
command = "pm install -r " + "/mnt/sdcard/Download/xxx.apk";                                               
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", command});
proc.waitFor();
```

Update is successfully, but UpdateReceiver not triggerd, so why?

My device OS verison is 4.4.4. and I update app from my own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not `android.intent.action.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. 
It is `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: official doc says , no need for pass data when api level > 12

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Have updated my answer. The action name is android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACE and not android.intent.action.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACE

Comment: Yes,thank you, my typo because of boss asking me quickly finish this:)